# Why does the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon switch sides?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

Why is it that in the very 1st *Star Wars*, when the Millennium Falcon  takes  off for the 1st time, the cockpit  is on the right of the Falcon. When  it's in the Death Star, the cockpit  is on the left  of  the Falcon. Why?

Comment: Could it be upside-down? There is no "up" in space...

Comment: I'm struggling to see which scene you're referring to. In my copy, in all of the Death Star scenes, the cockpit is on the right.

Comment: If you can't provide images of what you're talking about, then we are forced to conclude the premise is wrong.   If it were right, we would have heard about this all over the place over the last 40 years.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't

Taking off for the first time:

Official Canon (special edition)
[image]

Original (1977 version):
[image]
(source: http://www.dvdactive.com/editorial/articles/star-wars-the-changes-part-one.html)

In the Death Star:

[image]

The only thing changing is the camera's orientation in relation to the ship, thus changing which side of the *screen* the cockpit is on